# How to Save Items to IsolatedStorage and Populate a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, isolatedstorage

I have a class that contains a few items that I need to save to IsolatedStorage as well as populate into a ListBox. The class looks as follows

```
public class History
{
    public string Network {get; set;} 

    public DateTime Date {get; set;} 
}
```

And I will be using it to populate a ListBox of items with Network and Date combinations (the Network being the type of network connection that was detected when a button click event occurs). I simply just want to display a history of items in a ListBox that displays the detected Network connection type and Date that the network was detected. This data will only be determined on a click event. My main question is, how can I save this data to IsolatedStorage and then populate each occurance to a ListBox to show a history of detected network connections and their respective dates?

Comment: You can save the data in a database or an xml file that will live in your app's folder in isolated storage. The medium you choose it's just a matter of personal preference. Check [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/07/31/windows-phone-7-how-save-and-read-file-from-isolated-storage.aspx) how you save to /read from isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can SharpSerializer from nuget to do this.

here is how i did it

```
public static class IsolatedStorageOperations
    {
        public static async Task Save<T>(this T obj, string file)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = null;

                try
                {
                    stream = storage.CreateFile(file);
                    var serializer = new SharpSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(obj,stream);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        stream.Close();
                        stream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public static async Task<T> Load<T>(string file)
        {

            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            if (storage.FileExists(file))
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = null;
                try
                {
                    stream = storage.OpenFile(file, FileMode.Open);
                    var serializer = new SharpSerializer();

                    obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        stream.Close();
                        stream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                return obj;
            }
            await obj.Save(file);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

here obj is the List instance, where object is the instance of your class History. This List  will be the itemsource for ListBox